# In odoo 8 server "--auto-reload" when work

Tags: odoo-8

- Actually In the command of start odoo 8 server.
- It will provide "--auto-reload" option
- But actually i don't know how it works and when to work.
- Please if give me some guideline for that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally if you change your python code means, you need to restart the server in order to apply the new changes.

--auto-reload parameter is enabled means, you don't need to restart the server. It enables auto-reloading of python files and xml files without having to restart the server. It required [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki). It is a Python module for monitoring filesystems changes.

Just add --auto-reload in your configuration file. By default the value will be "false". You don't need to pass any extra arguments. --auto-reload is enough. If everything setup and works properly you will get

```
openerp.service.server: Watching addons folder /opt/odoo/v8.0/addons
openerp.service.server: AutoReload watcher running
```

in the server log. Don't forget to install pyinotify package.

Comment: after this answer i tested but its not working , what ever i change in python without restart server not applied in my module .. that --auto-reload is enable but also its not working

Comment: If any method to do this things , without restarting my server apply changes in module than please guide me

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check your log for "AutoReload watcher running" is present or not.

Comment: I installed `python-pyinotify`. I added `--auto-reload`, the server log also showed `AutoReload watcher running`, but my module wasn't automatically updated when the code was changed. Does anyone have the similar problem?

Comment: If you are using Vagrant and any virtual machine it might take some for pynotify to see the changes and the code might not be updated instantly.

Answer (score 3):

I found this looking for the same thing, but for odoo 10. Someone will follow the same route, so:

This has been changed in odoo 10 to --dev=reload. BUT you can't specify that in /etc/init.d/odoo itself. Only from the command line.