# Odoo service restart and update using systemctl

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9, systemctl, start-stop-daemon

Odoo service is started by `systemctl start odoo`. I am usin Centos. When I want to update my changed *.py code I used to do like this:

```
1. systemctl stop odoo
Then I update my module and database by useing this:
2. ./odoo.py -c openerp-server.conf -u <my_module_name> -d <database_name>
3. stop service by ctrl + c
4. systemctl start odoo
```

But it's realy long and uncomfortable way to update changes.

Is there a shorter way to do the same operations in shorter way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Odoo with Service

You can make changes like this:

1. Stop the server: `systemctl stop odoo`
2. Start the server: `systemctl start odoo`. Here the `.py` are updated
3. If you also need to update `xml` or some translations you can press the `Update` button on the Odoo interface, on the module description form.

**Note**: There are modules to reload specific xml views. If you are interested in it I can take a look to check if I find one.

### Odoo without Service

If you are developing on your local computer, you don´t need to use `systemctl`. Just run Odoo directly with `odoo.py` and you can see the changes immediately:

```
./odoo.py -c openerp-server.conf -u <my_module_name> -d <database_name>
```

### Autoreload Python Files

There is another option to reload python files when they have changed. Check this [**other answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247084/4891717):

> Normally if you change your python code means, you need to restart the
>   server in order to apply the new changes.
>
> `--auto-reload` parameter is enabled means, you don't need to restart the server. It enables auto-reloading of python files and xml files
>   without having to restart the server. It required
>   [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki). It is a Python
>   module for monitoring filesystems changes.
>
> Just add `--auto-reload` in your configuration file. By default the
>   value will be "false". You don't need to pass any extra arguments.
>   `--auto-reload` is enough. If everything setup and works properly you will get
>
> ```
> openerp.service.server: Watching addons folder /opt/odoo/v8.0/addons
> openerp.service.server: AutoReload watcher running in the server log. Don't forget to install pyinotify package.
> ```

But in odoo 10 just add `--dev=reload` paramter

```
--dev=DEV_MODE      Enable developer mode. Param: List of options
                    separated by comma. Options : all,
                    [pudb|wdb|ipdb|pdb], reload, qweb, werkzeug, xml
```

Comment: so for example: I change my_module_a and my_module_b.In openerp-server.conf I don't have any database filter and I am using 3 databases. So when I run systemctl start odoo, in all 3 databases .py will be updated? Hope you understand my question.

Comment: As I understand after service restart (systemctl start odoo) .py are automatically updated depend on filtered database on odoo-service.conf file?

Comment: Yes, if you update the python files, all the databases of the same instance are going to be updated. If you want to update the xml files you need to do it manually in every database you want

Answer (score 0):

```
Failed to stop odoo.service: Access denied. See system logs and 'systemctl status odoo.service' for details.
```

Initially, I got this error. Then tried with su and got this.

```
Failed to stop odoo.service: Unit odoo.service not loaded.
```

My concern is how to identify the perfect file through which I can restart the Odoo services post new module installation.